# Cocoa consistency

Tags: iphone, xcode

If I can write:

```
test_string = [[NSString alloc] init]; and
test_date   = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

Why, if only for reasons of consistency, can't I write:

```
test_integer = [[NSInteger alloc] init]; or
test_decimal = [[NSDecimal alloc] init];
```

and how do I set them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two examples are real objects, so they *must* be instantiated with `alloc`/`init` (or the shorthand form, `new`.

An `NSInteger` is just a typedef to `int` or `long`, depending on the platform, that is, it is just another name for either `int` or `long`. Those are both so-called *primitive types*. They're not real objects, but something much simpler. They don't have any methods, iVars, etc. - in fact, they really are just numbers, while an object representing a number (for example an `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`) is much more.

Primitive types are used when speed and memory efficiency are important, and integers are used so often that those considerations are important here. By the way, Smalltalk (the language that inspired Objective-C's syntax and object model) did not have primitive types. Even integers, even boolean values were objects. This was much more consistent (and more powerful in some regards), but it was one of the factors that made Smalltalk quite slow in the seventies and early eighties.

`NSDecimal` is also not an object, but a struct. A struct is essentially a list of named primitive values. Other often-used structs in Objective-C where this might be more obvious are `CGPoint` (A struct containing two floats, *x* and *y*), `CGSize` (again a struct containing two floats, this time called *width* and *height*), `CGRect` (a struct containing a `CGPoint` struct named *origin*, and a `CGSize` struct named *size*).

Comment: Thank you for that long and excellent explanation. Technically I don't see why a primative doesn't have to be init'ed so the compiler knows about it. Essentailly all data is a name, type, location (and maybe an offset).

Comment: A primitive is just the data found at a memory address, and the type tells the compiler how to interpret it (including how long it is). The type is not encoded anywhere within the primitive. An `int` with a value of 3 is literally just *00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101* in memory, nothing more.

Comment: So, `int myInteger = 5;` is the allocation and initialization. A space in memory with the right amount of bits for an `int` (32 bit on most systems) will be found, and *00000000000000000000000000000101* will be written there. and every time you access `myInteger`, the computer looks at that memory address and reads those 32 bits and interprets it as an int.

Comment: Typo in second comment: *...00000101* is 5, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [Number and Value Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/NumbersandValues.html) as a must read.

It will help you to begin with all this but remember that very often it will be easier to use the scalar values (C standard value types : int, float, long, etc.) unless you want specific use of them (store values in an NSArray, having a top nocht precision on calculus and avoid weird float rounding, etc.)